# Is there an exception if the connection with AD does not work?

Tags: c#, active-directory

In our code, we implemented a method where we get the users out of the AD (working with DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher). However, it can happen, that the connection with the AD is not possible. Is there any exception which is thrown if this connection does not work? Or maybe there is another way to handle a connection problem in my case?

Comment: You can use a timeout and if connection doesn't return a response within a period of time create an error message.

Comment: Look up the documentation of the involved methods. MS typically mentions all exceptions thrown by a method along with an explanation when it is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the connection cannot be made, then a `COMException` will be thrown with the message: "The server is not operational"

That message is not specific, however. It will happen for anything that prevents a connection from being established. For example:

- The DNS lookup failed
- The server cannot be reached (no network access)
- The SSL handshake failed, if using LDAPS (mismatched domain name or untrusted cert)

Comment: This means, I can just wrap my method, where I try to access the AD, with a try-catch block with the `COMException`?

Comment: @Michael you could try that by running your code locally after disconnecting your network.

Comment: Yes, you should use a try/catch block.